# c++ bmp to 2d-array prints unrealistic values

Tags: c++, 2d, bit, bmp

I'm having trouble with a small project that I'm doing.
I have to convert a bmp file to a 2d array of Color (I made my own typedef struct for each color).
The code works (it doesn't run into any errors) and some values are matching with the image but others don't; the 3 first pixels of my image are all white while he says they are first red, then green and finally blue.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

const int W = 960, H = 720;

typedef struct Colors {
    int red;
    int green;
    int blue;
} Color;


Color image[H][W];

void readBMP(char *filename) {
    FILE *f = fopen(filename, "rb");
    unsigned char info[54];
    fread(info, sizeof(unsigned char), 54, f); // read the 54-byte header

    // extract image height and width from header
    int width = *(int *) &info[18];
    int height = *(int *) &info[22];
    /* W = width;
    H = height;*/
    int size = 3 * width * height;
    unsigned char *data = new unsigned char[size]; // allocate 3 bytes per pixel
    fread(data, sizeof(unsigned char), size, f); // read the rest of the data at once
    fclose(f);
    int index = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < H; j++) {
        //cout << index << endl;
        for (int k = 0; k < W; k++) {
            index = (j * W) * 3 + k * 3;
            Color c;
            c.blue = (int) data[index];
            c.green = (int) data[index + 1];
            c.red = (int) data[index + 2];
            //cout << "j/width: " << (j / width) << endl << "j%width: " << (j % width) << endl << endl;
            image[j][k] = c;
            cout << (image[j][k]).red << ' ' << (image[j][k]).green << ' '     << (image[j][k]).blue << endl;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    //std::cout << "this is a test function" << endl;
    readBMP((char *) "test.bmp");
}
```

And the output of the first 50 lines is:

```
255 0 0
255 0 0
255 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0
71 66 255
128 115 82
40 245 194
30 184 96
133 32 21
64 1 235
19 51 51
102 102 128
102 64 38
160 6 102
9 153 153
215 10 60
92 36 3
0 50 143
0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0
4 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0
107 152 191
105 150 189
104 149 188
105 150 189
104 149 188
100 145 184
97 141 180
96 140 179
96 138 176
96 138 176
98 137 176
99 138 177
101 140 179
103 142 181
106 144 183
106 145 184
111 150 189
106 148 186
107 149 187
105 147 185
104 143 182
112 151 190
...
```

Thanks in advance,
Jari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a full bitmap parser it will only be able to read 24 bit bitmaps. It doesn't check for or read bitfield bitmaps, or clut based bitmaps.

Most importantly, as it's probably what's happening. 32 bit bitmaps will cause the channels to shift along to the next every time a colour is read. meaning most of the colours will be incorrect in some way.

You must check the bits per pixel in the header - it's an uint16_t  at the 15th & 16th bytes in the header.

But be aware there are quite a lot of other issues with this parser.